# Sprites don't move right at screen edges

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In the cocos2d game I am currently working on, I have certain sprites that are created to the right of the screen, move left across it at a fixed pace, and then get removed once they are off the screen.

This works great. BUT when the image hits the left side of the screen, it skips a beat then continues perfectly.

This is really noticeable because one element in my game that does this is 2d procedural terrain. My game generates an infinitely long set of hills, and it does this in rather small chunks. These chunks are placed immediately after one another and move across the screen together. But when the left edge of a chunk hits the left edge of the screen it is delayed a few pixels, and results in an ugly overlap.

I use the following code to move the chunks:

```
Chunk.position = CGPointMake(Chunk.position.x - panSpeed, Chunk.position.y);
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: How is the camera moving. Consistent speed or variable? (the panSpeed I assume is the camera?)

Comment: No camera is used. My game simply moves each chunk left using the code I posted. panSpeed is a calculated value that is used to move the chunks. This value is calculated once every frame and the same value is used for all chunks every frame, as it doesn't recalculate until the next frame. So I assume this is an issue with cocos2d, because each are shifted the exact same distance but when one hits the left edge of the screen it doesn't move properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not factoring in the time delta in the update..
Look at the code for `CCMoveTo` action:

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) t
{   
    [target_ setPosition: ccp( (startPosition.x + delta.x * t ), (startPosition.y + delta.y * t ) )];
}
```

Comment: Delta time simply puts movement into a fixed pixels/second rather than pixels/frame so that if the frame rate changes the real world speed does not.

Comment: The panSpeed variable factors in delta time. It isn't that they all skip a beat, it is only the image that starts to exit the screen, the rest all go properly.

Comment: It is only the code I already provided. Using only that line of code, only the images that aren't ENTIRELY on the screen lag, and that is my problem.